Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch 8.14.8 BulkAll methods
I have a elasticsearch 8.2 installed on my windows 11 machine.
In my dot.net core 6 console application i use nuget package Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch version 8.14.8 to call elastic to do search and crud action.
Search and single CRUD work well, but i have more issue if i use bulk action.
I try to use BulkAll methods but i haven't any type of response or error.
Code ElasticsearchClient:
private static ElasticsearchClient ElasticClient()
        {
            if (_elasticClient != null)
            {
                return _elasticClient;
            }

            var nodPool = new SingleNodePool(new Uri(ElasticAddress));

            var clientSettings = new ElasticsearchClientSettings(
                nodePool: nodPool,
                    sourceSerializer: (builtin, setting) => new DocumentIndexSerializer())
                    .DefaultIndex(IndexName)
                    .DefaultMappingFor<DocumentIndex>(m => m.IdProperty(p => p.GlobalChunkId))
                    .DefaultFieldNameInferrer(f => f)
                    .DisableDirectStreaming()
                    .EnableDebugMode()
                                        .OnRequestDataCreated(data =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n### DATA PROCESSED ###");
                        Console.WriteLine($"{data.ContentType}");
                    })
                    .OnRequestCompleted(details =>
                    {
                        if (details.RequestBodyInBytes != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\n### REQUEST ###");
                            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(details.RequestBodyInBytes));
                        }
                        if (details.ResponseBodyInBytes != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\n### RESPONSE ###");
                            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(details.ResponseBodyInBytes));
                        }
                    })
                    .PrettyJson();


            _elasticClient = new ElasticsearchClient(clientSettings);


            return _elasticClient;
        }

BulkAll code:

var bulkAllObservable = ElasticClient().BulkAll<DocumentIndex>(documents, b => b
                .Index(IndexName)
                .BackOffTime("30s")
                .BackOffRetries(2)
                .RefreshOnCompleted()
                .MaxDegreeOfParallelism(Environment.ProcessorCount)
                .Size(ElasticSearchMaxDocumentBulkAll)
            );


            var waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);

            ExceptionDispatchInfo exceptionDispatchInfo = null;

            var observer = new BulkAllObserver(
                onNext: response =>
                {
                    if (TraceVerbose)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"PARTIAL INDEX COUNT: {response.Items.Count}");
                    }
                },
                onError: exception =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error in ElasticClient.BulkAll(INDEX/UPDATE) :{exception.Message}");
                    exceptionDispatchInfo = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(exception);
                    waitHandle.Set();
                },
                onCompleted: () =>
                {
                    if (TraceVerbose)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"COMPLETE INDEX COUNT: {count}");
                    }
                    waitHandle.Set();
                });

            bulkAllObservable.Subscribe(observer);

            waitHandle.WaitOne();

            exceptionDispatchInfo?.Throw();

ElasticsearchClient seems to work correctly for single document operations like search, index, and update. However, when executing the BulkAll method, the code gets stuck in waitHandle.WaitOne(); without any errors or exceptions. I've tried removing waitHandle and forcing an index refresh after BulkAll, but it didn't resolve the issue. This code used to work with the older Elastic client 7.17 version
Thank you for any hit.
